# Android: save sound as ringtone / SQLiteConstraintException

Tags: android, exception, sqlite, ringtone

I'm trying to save a sound as a ringtone in Android using [this](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-saving-a-sound-file-to-sd-from-resource-and-setting-as-ringtone/) code. It works like a charm but will fail if I try to save a ringtone that has already been inserted.

A "SQLiteConstraintException" occurs while saving but I'm not able to catch the exception, in fact, I can't catch *any* execption.

Here's the part of my code:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());

try {
  this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
} catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
  Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
} catch (SQLiteException e) {
  Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
}
```

So I'm trying to actually catch any possible exception, but *none* is caught.

This is the LogCat:

```
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217): Error inserting album_id=-1 title=Applause is_notification=true title_key=%,%J%J%B%,%T%P%4% mime_type=audio/ogg date_added=1286908371 _display_name=Applause.ogg is_alarm=true is_ringtone=true artist_id=1 is_music=false _data=/mnt/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/Applause.ogg
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:1813)
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:1638)
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:174)
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:146)
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
10-12 18:32:51.627: ERROR/Database(217):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I found a workaround: I check if the soundfile exists before I call the .insert-method (and don't call it, if the file's already there), but I'd really like to understand why no exception is caught. Hope anybody can help me out.

Kind regards,
Select0r

Comment: the link to "using this code" helped me... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not caught because the exception is not in your code. It is not even in your process. It is in the process of the `MediaStore` content provider.

Comment: Ok, that explains why the LogCat doesn't show me a file and line number of one of *my* files :) So does that mean there's no chance for me to get hold of that exception?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue....it's because you don't have this permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Also, if you're using that tutorial, make sure you have this in your manifest as well...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I spent a good half an hour or so trying to figure out why the code wasn't working.  I actually removed the try/catch just to see what type of error it would throw in the logcat, and it told me I was missing those permissions.

Comment: Nope, read my post again, my issue was not permission-related.