# Store information in audio file

Tags: android

I want to store information like artist while recording an MP3 file.   :

```
public class AudioCap extends Activity {  
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";  
    private static String mFileName = null;  

    private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;  
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;  

    private PlayButton mPlayButton = null;    
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;  

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {  
        if (start) {  
            startRecording();  
    }       else {  
            stopRecording();  
    }  
     }  

    private void onPlay(boolean start) {  
        if (start) {  
            startPlaying();  
        }   else {  
            stopPlaying();  
        }  
    } 

    private void startPlaying() {  
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();  
         try {  
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);  
            mPlayer.prepare();  
            mPlayer.start();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
             Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");  
        }  
    }  

private void stopPlaying() {
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
}

private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}

class RecordButton extends Button {
    boolean mStartRecording = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onRecord(mStartRecording);
            if (mStartRecording) {
                setText("Stop recording");
            } else {
                setText("Start recording");
            }
            mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
        }
    };

    public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Start recording");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}

class PlayButton extends Button {
    boolean mStartPlaying = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onPlay(mStartPlaying);
            if (mStartPlaying) {
                setText("Stop playing");
            } else {
                setText("Start playing");
            }
            mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
        }
    };

    public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Start playing");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}

public AudioCap() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.mp3";
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
    ll.addView(mRecordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    0));
    mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
    ll.addView(mPlayButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    0));
    setContentView(ll);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

}

I have following code to record my audio file in mp3 format. But details can't be added to it. So is there any way so that I can store some metadata through my android activity/java program into my recorded audio file.

Regards,
Sneha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the audio info in the `MediaStore`

```
    ContentResolver mCr = app.getContentResolver();
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, your_sound_file.getAbsolutePath());
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Name Of Your File");
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, your_sound_file.length());
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Artist Name");
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
      //Now set some extra features it depend on you
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

   Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(your_file.getAbsolutePath());
   Uri uri2= mCr.insert(uri, values);
```

Please check if the sound file already exists before you call the `insert` method .Make sure that you are not calling it if the file's already there.
The exception is not caught because the exception is not in your code. It is not even in your process. It is in the process of the MediaStore content provider.

Agin these links can help you out

[Setting Ringtone notification from SD card file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029876/setting-ringtone-notification-from-sd-card-file)

[Android: save sound as ringtone / SQLiteConstraintException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918034/android-save-sound-as-ringtone-sqliteconstraintexception)

Comment: Hi  May I know what type is the variable mCr above??

Comment: thanks, but wat's app type?? I have just tried ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();   It did not work.

Comment: You must use a `Context` object  to use  the `getContentResolver` method.

Comment: 'Context c=getApplicationContext();' ContentResolver mCr = c.getContentResolver(); super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); File src=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/laserspure.mp3"); ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, src.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: the above code throws exception. 05-26 10:03:54.316: ERROR/Database(213): Error inserting album_id=-1 title=BFN title_key=%.%6%F% mime_type=audio/mpeg date_added=1306384434 _display_name=laserspure.mp3 is_ringtone=true _size=63573 artist_id=2 _data=/mnt/sdcard/laserspure.mp3

Comment: Try to pass context as `YourActivityName.this`

Comment: Do I have to add any permission in manifest?? I  have used <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> it did not work!

Comment: Seems that you are not saving the file in your sdcard.

Comment: I did save it in sdcard. It throws some SQLite exception

Comment: Are you sure that it is being saved in sdcard.Also post ur full logcat

Comment: I have posted my Log Cat as answer as i couldn't edit it as comment

Comment: Edited the answer.Hope it will help you.Thanks .:)

Comment: Hey thanks. But i did not get u clearly. I have used File src=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/laser1.mp3");  so do i have to have a file named 'laser1.mp3' in my sdcard or not??

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=12296), This example desribes how to extract id3 tags from mp3 file. I think process to store information to mp3 is similar

Link to [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html)